# select all '77' intervals from array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array full of data - but the data crossed with 77  intervals (that have different length)
like this

```
[-1, 2, 2, 4, -5, 77, 77, 77, 6, 5, 34, 77, 77, 4, 7...]
```

There is no problem to find any start or finish index of this interval but I need to save their indexes somehow(?) array (as I thought) is not good for this (but perhaps there is a solution how to do this. writing in matrix? but the results have different dimensions.. 
so for input

```
[-1, 2, 2, 4, -5, 77, 77, 77, 6, 5, 34, 77, 77, 4, 7...]
```

expected an answer

```
[6,7,8]
[12,13]
```

indexes starts from 1. How could I do it?

Comment: Could you please explain further what you are trying to achieve? If you need the indices of all elements matching `77` in order to remove them from your data this can instead be done by using `A(A==77)=[]`, where `A` is your data vector. If you want to find all indices and store them you could do this in a single vector using `find(A==77)` which would give you a single vector of indices `[6,7,8,12,13]`.

Comment: use cell arrays to store your results. This way you can have different number of indices in each cell entry.

Comment: user1884905, I need a number of arrays that is equal to number of intervals every of them contains indexes of this elements/ Shai, thank for the help - I ll try to find some info about cell arrays and implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing what you want. The final indices are collected in a cell `F`. I have included all printouts in the comments so that you can step through it, but I'll briefly explain what I'm doing because it's quite an ugly solution.

Using a vector `A` for the data, I first find all indices that match `77` by using `find()`. I then want to cut this vector up at positions where the difference between two consecutive indices is greater than one. I want to use `mat2cell()` to convert the vector into a cell so I again use `diff()` to get all lengths.

```
A = [-1, 2, 2, 4, -5, 77, 77, 77, 6, 5, 34, 77, 77, 4, 7];
B = find(A==77);             %// B = [6  7  8  12  13]
C = diff(B);                 %// C = [1  1  4  1]
D = find(C~=1);              %// D = [3]
E = diff([0 D length(B)]);   %// E = [3  2]
F = mat2cell(B,1,E);         %// F = [1x3 double] [1x2 double]

%// F{1} = [6   7   8]
%// F{2} = [12 13]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `diff` to detect start and end of each run, and `arrayfun` to create the cell array of consecutive indices:

```
data = [-1, 2, 2, 4, -5, 77, 77, 77, 6, 5, 34, 77, 77, 4, 7]; %// example data

aux = diff(data==77); %// add dummy value at end, in case final data is 77
starts = find(aux==1)+1;
if data(1)==77 %// special case: start with a run
    starts = [1 starts];
end
ends = find(aux==-1);
if data(end)==77  %// special case: end with a run
    ends = [ends numel(data)];
end
result = arrayfun(@(n) starts(n):ends(n), 1:length(starts), 'uni', false);
```

With the example data, this gives:

```
>> result{1}

ans =

     6     7     8

>> result{2}

ans =

    12    13
```

Comment: result = arrayfun(@(n) starts(n):ends(n), 1:length(starts)-1, 'uni', false);

Comment: @curiousity Why `-1`? You then lose the last run

Comment: Attempted to access ends(310); index out of bounds because numel(ends)=310. if -1 this solution corresponds to use1884905 result

Comment: @curiousity I don't get it. If numel(ends) is 310, how is it you can't access ends(310)?

Comment: @curiousity Sorry. Corrected. Please try now

Comment: Thank you,Luis - could you recommend something to read about cell arrays? Especially creation/loop through/remove element? (help a  matlab dummy please! =) )

Comment: I don't know many references other than Matlab's help itself. But this is probably a good reference: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html And also Loren's blog is well known, she probably explains good stuff here http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/ disclaimer: I haven't actually read any of these references :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it is

```
[6,8]
[12,13]
```

that you want,

and answer is

```
m=[-1, 2, 2, 4, -5, 77, 77, 77, 6, 5, 34, 77, 77, 4, 7]
r=[find([1,m]~=77&[m,1]==77);find([m,1]~=77&[1,m]==77)-1]'
```

And to obtain exactly what you asked:

```
for bounds=[find([1,m]~=77&[m,1]==77);find([m,1]~=77&[1,m]==77)-1];
  disp(bounds(1):bounds(2))
end
```

Replace ~=77 by >=0 and ==77 by <0 if you want to test for negatives numbers instead of 77.

Comment: disp([find([1,m]~=77&[m,1]==77);find([m,1]~=77&[1,m]==77)-1]') now shows:
     6     8
    12    13

Comment: this is pretty good, but I need this answers as vectors(to know how may such intervals)(( damn, in c# there is no such problems - it is possible to save any object you d like

Comment: Didn't @curiousity ask for `[6,7,8]`, and not just `[6 8]`? The fact that the rows of 77's are of different lengths is specified in the question. Or am I wrong @curiosity?

Comment: @curiousity I think solution is your best bet (better imo that what you asked for). You can see how many such intervals as follows (I assume you store this solution in a vector `I`): `size(I,1)`. And you can tell how many 77s are in each range by `diff(I') + 1`.

Comment: yes, Robert P you are right. In fact I am searching negative values in that array and trying to store them to the vectors as I describe above but I decide not overload a question - so write 77 - perhaps this is not right here. Dan, but I don't know how many elements in every vector. This question is about simple - sub-set cutting) but in matlab it is not so simple(